# Finding initial and final objects of a category

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading a great textbook "Algebra: Chapter 0" by Paolo Aluffi and I've got some troubles understanding a very basic thing.

Let $∼$ be an equivalence relation defined on a set A.

> The quotient $A/∼$ is universal with respect to the property of
>   mapping $A$ to a set in such a way that equivalent elements have the
>   same image.

So the object in this category is some function $\phi:\ A \rightarrow Z\ $ satisfying $\ a'∼a''⇒\phi(a')=\phi(a'').$
Morphisms are commutative diagrams $(\phi_{1},Z_{1}) \rightarrow (\phi_{2},Z_{2})$

I had no troubles understanding that $ (\pi,A/∼)$ is the initial object in this category and proved it by myself before reading author's proof.

The thing is that i can't come up with a proof that  $im\ f$ of some $f: A\rightarrow B$ also satisfies this universal property, i.e. that $im\ f$ is an initial object of this category as well and $A/∼ \ \cong \ im\ f$

Suppose we have the following morphism $\sigma: (f, im\ f)\rightarrow(\phi, Z)$

Can I state that from $\ \ (f∘\sigma)(a') = \phi(a'') ⇒ a'∼a''\ \ $ it follows that $\sigma$ is unique and well-defined? If so, can I say further that any object $(\phi, Z)$ is a final/terminal one in this category?

To sum up, I need to find the final object in this category and prove $im\ f$ is an initial object. I feel that I can't do the former without solid understanding of the latter.

Could you help me please?

Comment: You'll need some assumptions about $f$ for that. (Or if you just wan't _one_ such $f$, you have it already: you just called it $\pi$ rather than $f$).

Comment: well, isn't $\ f(a') = f(a'') ⇒ a' ∼ a'' \ $ enough?

Comment: x @Atin: Yes, but I don't see that assumption stated anywhere in your question.

Comment: Well, I've written it when I was defining an object of a category, I mean that any function in this category satisfies this property. Nevertheless, I think I should edit my question and write this assumption since it is indeed can be missed easily, my bad.

Comment: x @Atin: No, what you wrote in that definition was the _opposite_ implication. $P\Rightarrow Q$ and $Q\Rightarrow P$ are not the same.

Comment: Oh, now I see my fault. I should have defined $f(a′)=f(a′′)⇔a′∼a′′$ and then my reasoning $(f∘σ)(a′)=ϕ(a′′)⇒a′∼a′′ $ is correct and now I can understand why $im f$ is an initial object. But now I really have no idea what is the final object of this category. Anyway, thanks for clarifying

Comment: x @Atin: Try a one-element set and the unique function into it.